# Postman | API Chaining

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, postman

I have to automate these-

1. Get a list of employees in the USA:

   **GET** `/emps/usa`
2. Get each user's details:

   **GET** `/emps/empid`

The first API returns data like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "firstName": "Tom",
    "lastName": "Cruise"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "firstName": "Maria",
    "lastName": "Sharapova"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "firstName": "James",
    "lastName": "Bond"
  }
]
```

Now, for each employee I need to call a 2nd API to get details per `id`.

**Problem**: I created a collection with above mentioned API's.
After the first API call, in Postman's *Tests* section I am reading the
response values in a loop.
My problem is: how can I read and hold data for each employee `id` and then
call the 2nd API in the collection as many times I have received an employee
`id`?
Is there any way to call an API from Postman's *Tests* section?
Or any other working idea?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried passing data from file(csv or json) at collection runner.
This solution will work if you have all your id's for which you want details in file
Then pass number of iterations accordingly.

Efficient solution (when you get different ids in response of first request) will be using **newman** command-line collection runner for Postman.
You need to create two separate collection in **postman app**

1. Get Id's : which will have **GET /emps/usa** request

Get all id's from "GET /emps/usa" and store it in environment variable as "," seperated string,
 To do this you can parse your JSON response 
Create empty string variable which will be appended every Id string in iteration according to size of array which you get in response
Then set the result string which will look like "1,2,3" to environment variable

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("allIds",result);
```

Once you get expected string in environment variable, you done with postman step1 :)
Now its time export collection and run this collection from commanline tool
exported collection and environment from **postman** is in json format 
let say *getData.json* is your collection file and *env.json* is your environment file

from cmd prompt or shell execute following:

```
newman run getData.json -e env.json --export-environment expEnv.json
```

when you execute this you will get expEnv.json which will have id data generated during execution
Now scary part comes (process expEnv.json)
Here you need to write a program in programming language you like which will take this expEnv.json process/parse it and create **csv** file
format of csv will be like: 
Id
1
2
3
Once you get this thing in csv then you can move to step 2.
 
2. Get each user details: **GET /emps/empid** request
In postman app create a collection with get detail request
In Pre Request Script you need to set value from file to environment variable 
Your pre req script will look like:
`postman.setEnvironmentVariable('usrId',data['Id']);`//refer [answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39842552/value-not-substiuting-in-postman-runner-collection/39910854#39910854)

Now change your URL by adding usrId in url from environment variable
 url will look like **GET /emps/{{usrId}}** instead of GET /emps/empid
Then export this collection and run it from newman 
let say getDetails.json is exported collection from postman you can use same env.json here

```
newman run getDetails.json -e env.json -d yourGeneratedCSVFile.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to use postman control workflow ?
You have a great example with [Cooper's meal plan](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/583/coopers-meal-plan/4u2).
The keys are :

1. Implement a standard loop, but persist your index in environment variable.
2. Do whatever you need, check for persisted index and while needed use postman.setNextRequest("<requestName>").

Answer (score 0):

I have a working solution to this question.

#### 1. Prerequisites

My two APIs / endpoints are as follows.

- [`/emps/usa`](http://henke.atwebpages.com/postman/chaining/emps/usa):

```
{
  "US-employees": [
    {
      "id": "Q37079",
      "name": "Tom Cruise"
    },
    {
      "id": "Q844",
      "name": "James Bond"
    },
    {
      "id": "Q11666",
      "name": "Maria Sharapova"
    }
  ]
}
```

- [`/emps/empid`](http://henke.atwebpages.com/postman/chaining/emps/empid):

```
{
  "US-portraits": [
    {
      "id": "Q844",
      "description": "Fictional British spy",
      "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/ [...] _Bangalore_144323.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": "Q11666",
      "description": "Russian tennis player",
      "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/ [...] _%2843186339350%29.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": "Q37079",
      "description": "American actor and producer",
      "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/ [...] _Skidmore_2.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

where I have truncated the links of the images for better readability.
(Just click the
[`/emps/empid`](http://henke.atwebpages.com/postman/chaining/emps/empid)
link to see the unabbreviated version.)

Notice in the first endpoint how each object / person has a unique
`id` and a `name`, nothing more.
The second API has – for each object in the first endpoint – the same
unique identifier, along with a description and a link to an image /
portrait.
Thus, neither of the two APIs on its own contains information on *both* the
name and the image link.

#### 2. The result

Obviously, the problem is solved if the data in the two APIs can be combined
together in such a way that – for each identifier – *both* the name and the
image link are supplied. Like so:

```
[
  {
    "id": "Q37079",
    "name": "Tom Cruise",
    "description": "American actor and producer",
    "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/ [...] _Skidmore_2.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "Q844",
    "name": "James Bond",
    "description": "Fictional British spy",
    "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/ [...] _Bangalore_144323.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "Q11666",
    "name": "Maria Sharapova",
    "description": "Russian tennis player",
    "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/ [...] _%2843186339350%29.jpg"
  }
]
```

All that remains is to visualize the data in Postman:

[image: Visualized Result in Postman]

#### 3. Methodology

I make the request to the
[`/emps/usa`](http://henke.atwebpages.com/postman/chaining/emps/usa) API as a
normal **GET** request in Postman:

```
GET http://henke.atwebpages.com/postman/chaining/emps/usa
```

I probably could have made the request to the
[`/emps/empid`](http://henke.atwebpages.com/postman/chaining/emps/empid) API
as an ordinary Postman request too – and then combined the two
requests via Postman's Collection  Runner.

But instead I make the request to the
[`/emps/empid`](http://henke.atwebpages.com/postman/chaining/emps/empid) API
in a *Pre-request* script, as follows:

```
const url = 'http://henke.atwebpages.com/postman/chaining/emps/empid';
pm.sendRequest(url, (err, response) => {
  pm.environment.set('US_portraits',
    JSON.stringify(response.json()['US-portraits']));
});
```

Then, in the *Tests* section, I combine the two results together, and
finally visualize them:

```
const usEmployees = pm.response.json()['US-employees'];
const usPortraits = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get('US_portraits'));
usEmployees.map(x => Object.assign(x, usPortraits.find(y => y.id === x.id)));
const tblHeader = Object.keys(pm.response.json())[0];
const template = `
<table>
  <tr><th>` + tblHeader + `</th></tr>
  {{#each response}}
  <tr><td>{{name}}<br><img src="{{image}}"></td></tr>
  {{/each}}
</table>`;
pm.visualizer.set(template, {
  response: usEmployees
});
```

#### 4. How to replicate my solution in Postman

Replicating my results in Postman should be straightforward.
Assuming you are using [the desktop version of Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/), do as follows:

1. Download and save
   http://henke.atwebpages.com/postman/chaining/emps/API-Chaining.pm_coll.json
   in a suitable place on your hard drive.
2. In Postman, *<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> > Upload Files >
   `API-Chaining.pm_coll.json` > Import*.
   You should now see `API Chaining` among your collections in Postman.
3. *Collections > `API Chaining` > `US-empl-request` > **Send***.
4. In the Postman Response Body, click *Visualize*.
5. Done! – If everything worked as intended, you should now see the output as
   in the image above, starting with the name and image of Tom Cruise.

#### 5. Two questions by the original poster + one extra

**Question**
*how can I read and hold data for each employee id and then call the 2nd API
in the collection as many times I have received an employee id?*

**Answer**
I call the two APIs just once each, and then do whatever needed with the data
retrieved.
I get *two* JavaScript arrays, one from each of the two APIs.
The essence of the problem boils down to joining two JavaScript arrays that
have a common unique identifier.

---

**Question**
*Is there any way to call an API from Postman's Tests section?*

**Answer**
Yes! – In the above solution, I make the necessary API requests *before* the
*Tests* section kicks in.
Then I devote the *Tests* section to getting the data from the requests –
saved in two environment variables – and finally manipulate that data to
reach the end goal.

But you can do it *all* in *Tests*. See the last section below.

---

**Question**
*But hey, this isn't chaining any more! –
There is no *second* request using information from the *first* request.
Right?*

**Answer**
That's right! – It doesn't matter which request is put in the *Pre-request*
script, and which is run as the *ordinary* request. Swapping them should work
just as fine. The point is: the asker of the question thought of the problem
as a need to make *chaining* requests.
(And I present one such solution in the next section.)
It turns out that *chaining* requests are not *necessary* to solve the
problem.

#### 6. Doing it *all* in the *Tests* section

You can actually do literally *everything* in the *Tests* script.

Although chaining requests are not strictly necessary to solve the problem,
here is a solution with code *only* in the *Tests* section, which *does*
apply a second chaining request.
The second request does not depend on any data from the first request, but the
second *callback* needs data from both requests.
(The main request is just a dummy request never used – except for start
running the *Tests* script.)

Both requests are made in the script, then combined, and finally visualized:
<sup>1</sup>

```
const lock = setTimeout(() => {}, 43210);
const urlO = 'http://henke.atwebpages.com/postman/chaining/emps/empid';
const urlI = 'http://henke.atwebpages.com/postman/chaining/emps/usa';
pm.sendRequest(urlO, (_, responseO) => {
  const usPortraits = responseO.json()['US-portraits'];
  pm.sendRequest(urlI, (_, responseI) => {
    clearTimeout(lock); // Unlock the timeout.
    const usEmployees = responseI.json()['US-employees'];
    usEmployees.map(x => Object.assign(x,
      usPortraits.find(y => y.id === x.id)));
    const tblHeader = Object.keys(responseI.json())[0];
    const template = `<table>
      <tr><th>` + tblHeader + `</th></tr>
      {{#each responseI}}
      <tr><td>{{name}}<br><img src="{{image}}"></td></tr>
      {{/each}}
    </table>`;
    pm.visualizer.set(template, { responseI: usEmployees });
  });
});
```

Postman Collection to replicate this *Tests-only* version:
http://henke.atwebpages.com/postman/chaining/emps/API-Chain.sendReq.pm_coll.json.

#### References

- [Saving Data from a Request – to be Retrieved and Used Elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41539475)
- [Left Outer Join Between Two JavaScript Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35904655)
- [Wikidata on Tom Cruise](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q37079)
- [Wikidata on James Bond](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q844)
- [Wikidata on Maria Sharapova](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q11666)
- [Postman workaround for known bug: chained requests never getting executed](https://community.postman.com/t/using-native-javascript-promises-in-postman/636)

---

<sup>1</sup> Don't get confused by the lines
`const lock = setTimeout(() => {}, 43210);` and `clearTimeout(lock);`. –
Their only purpose is to serve as [a workaround for a known bug](https://community.postman.com/t/using-native-javascript-promises-in-postman/636).